# error occur while parsing the data from the web service

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

Occur error while parsing here iam using JSON Parser
see the below code

```
- (void)loadDataSource  {  
    // Request  
    NSString *URLPath = [NSString   stringWithFormat:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?   v=1.0&q=Official%20Google%20Blogs"];      
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLPath];  
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        NSInteger responseCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

        if (!error && responseCode == 200) {
            id res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
            if (res && [res isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                self.items = [res objectForKey:@"gallery"];
                [self dataSourceDidLoad];
            } else {
                [self dataSourceDidError];
            }
        } else {
            [self dataSourceDidError];
        }
    }];
}
```

i put the break point,it was skipped from NSURL Connection.consider if any mistakes for the above code

thanks in advance

Comment: you should post what error message you got

Comment: Error is "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" "@rdelmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's white space in your Url. Make sure the url is correct.